# How to control table and its title to appear on the same page

Tags: tables

**Problem:** Table's title appears on a different page, and it looks really bad.

The next mage shows what I need to fix:

("Cuadro 4.2" means "Table 4.2" in English. That is the title added by `captionof`.)

[image]

The code I am using for tables looks like this:

```
   \begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Convergencia pm6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_pm6}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-SS} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-Packmol} \\ \hline
    5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
    10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
    15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
    20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
    30 & -65.9 & -66.3 \\ \hline
    40 & -67.2 & -65.6 \\ \hline
    50 & -66.7 & -65.3 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

Any help?

Comment: To be able to test suggestions, a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be helpfull. For now I could only suggest to enclose table and caption in a minipage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
\captionof{table}{Convergencia pm6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_pm6}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-SS} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-Packmol} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
30 & -65.9 & -66.3 \\ \hline
40 & -67.2 & -65.6 \\ \hline
50 & -66.7 & -65.3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

of course, for this you need add `\usepackage{float}` to document preamble. however, such solution (also with use of `minipage` for the same effect) is -- to my opinion --
against to latex "philosophy" of nice document formatting. I would rather use:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Convergencia pm6-cluster}
      \label{table:convergencia_cluster_pm6}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-SS} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-Packmol} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
30 & -65.9 & -66.3 \\ \hline
40 & -67.2 & -65.6 \\ \hline
50 & -66.7 & -65.3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

this allows to float table to the next page (as at first solution) but also enable to fill empty space on previous page with text after inserting a table in document.  otherwise you will have there (ugly) empty space.

Comment: I have had too many problems to set tables with that environment, that is why I changed to `\begin{center}`. I will try it anyway

Comment: for suggested solution you can employ your editor :) find/replace function take less effort as adding `minipage`s to your `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` (to my opinion) ...

Answer (score 3):

Use a `minipage` environment to prevent the caption and the table from being separated by a pagebreak:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Convergencia pm6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_pm6}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-SS} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-Packmol} \\ \hline
        5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
        10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
        15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
        20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
        30 & -65.9 & -66.3 \\ \hline
        40 & -67.2 & -65.6 \\ \hline
        50 & -66.7 & -65.3 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: You might need a `\noindent` before `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: I don't know why `minipage` produces lot of space below the table

Comment: isn't it more natural to enclose tabular material in `table` environment (with `[H]` option?)

Comment: It's hard to tell what is happening without you showing us a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) @HernanMiraola

Comment: @Zarko: I agree, but it seems the questioner doesn't want to have a floating environment.

Comment: Can two `minipages` be defined in the same page?

Comment: @Tiuri, but your solutiion also "float" to the next page if for it is not enough space on page (i corrected suggested table option to H).

Comment: @Zarko I am using `\captionof` to avoid floats, it was suggested by cfr. Maybe that is why now, tables and graphs are so far, it is not working well

Comment: @Zarko any solution without changing the environment of the OP?

Comment: @Zarko: Of course, `\begin{table}[H]` will pretty much do the same, maybe with better margins, and with the ease of using `\caption` instead of `\captionof{table}`. So it's probably worth an answer for itself. I want to keep this answer, however, to show the "simple" way with minimal adjustments.

Comment: any solution without changing the environment of the OP? (because of the floating I have some graphs and tables which have been repositioned, I need to avoid it)

Comment: @HernanMiraola: **Please** show us a full Minimal Working Example, otherwise we will not be able to give you a more solid advice.

Comment: @Tiuri I have read not to use` [H]` option

Comment: @Tiuri I have a complex document, and when I tried to make a MWE it changed a lot; that is why I didn't upload a MWE on OP

Comment: @HernanMiraola Well, then we will not be able to help you properly. Try this: Take an almost empty document (right documentclass, only the packages needed for this table), include the package `lipsum` and then put `\lipsum[1-3]` and the table into this document. Adjust the argument of `lipsum` until you get as much text as you need to have a pagebreak between the caption and the table.

Comment: @HernanMiraola As Tiuri says, it's not really possible to say for sure. My wild guess is that you have two `minipage` environments after each other, each with a table in it, and that there are not room for both on the same page. You can have multiple `minipage`s on the same page, but there has to be room for them. If this is the case, then my advice would be to actually use floats -- the purpose of floats is precisely to let LaTeX move such big elements around in order to avoid bad page breaks/half empty pages.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. below the first `minipage` I have `\begin{center}` to center an image..I think I will try with floats

Comment: @HernanMiraola Well, the same principle applies, if there isn't room for the image on the page, it will move to the next page.

Comment: @HernanMiraola You have one choice: Let LaTeX do the positioning of tables and figures, or do it yourself. Both posted solutions make you the master general and you are fully resposible for positioning. Including any white space and bad page breaks that arise from it.